# TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'message' of object 'SyntaxError: unknown: Missing semicolon. (1:12)

Tags: mongodb, bson, mongodump

I am New to Mongo and Started Learning from Mango Basics.
i am following the course and when I tried to write the Mongodump it is giving "SyntaxError: Missing semicolon. (1:12)"
Can anybody guide me on Solving this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8HUu.png)

I found this answer but didn't undersant what is means
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xn1Ll.png)

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stack Overflow.  It's better to post the code (even though it loses the colour) than links to images.  People need to see everything together because it's easier to understand, and in 5 years time it'll still be here.  It looks like youv'e started Mongosh, then run Mongodump from within it. Mongodump needs to be run from the command line. so exit mongosh, and try again. 
 Paragraph 2 here: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongodump/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.